# which value does javascript function takes if the function is called in the given example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in `javascript` and trying to make `todo` in pure `javascript` only.

I have got an input field.

```
input(type="text", placeholder="Type here", id="new-todo", name="newTodo")
```

When i call a `function` to create a new `todo` then at first `function` will check the input `id` or the `name` of input.

Suppose i have got a pond and it consist of two kind of fish only
and when i go for fishing with a fishing stick in that pond then which kind of fish will the fishing stick will catch at first.

In above i am comparing the pond with `input`, two kind of fish as `id` and `name`
and fishing stick with the `function` which i will call to create new `todo`.

Can anyone can explain me to understand this problem please...

Comment: "Can anyone can explain me to understand this problem please..." 8)

Comment: Mainly id of the element will be referenced by Javascript. name is like optional, but it goes by id value .

Comment: you lost me at the "pond"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the same analogy of `pond`, `fishes` and the `fishing stick`.

Pond is a `form`. Fishes are its `elements` (not attributes id or name). Each fish / element has their own `name` and `id`. Now you can catch the fish by either of its property id or name.

In javascript :

`document.getElementById("firstFishId")` and `document.forms[0].firstFishName` will provide you the same element if you have following markup in your html.

```
<form> <!-- This is a pond -->

<input type="text" name="firstFishName" id="firstFishId" /> <!-- this is a fish with id `firstFishId` and a name `firstFishName` -->

<input type="text" name="secondFishName" id="secondFishId" /> <!-- this is a fish with id `secondFishId` and a name `secondFishName` -->

</form>
```

Hope It helps you to understand a bit.